# Value for UITabelView background color on iPad

Tags: ipad, uitableview

Need to make a matching graphic, does anyone know the color value of the iPad UITableView background color?

Comment: In Interface Builder a tableView for an iPad view is white.

Comment: Are you referring to the grouped style tableview background colour?

Answer (score 0):

It is a gradient of different shades of gray, not a solid color.

But a close enough color is 0xdddddd.